# How to write a double value byte by byte

Tags: lua, double, byte

I have to communicate with a dll and it lua and this is the function I use to write strings by bytes:

```
writeString = function(pid, process, address, value)
        local i = 1
        while i <= String.Length(value) do
            local byte = string.byte(value, i, i)
            DLL.CallFunction("hook.dll", "writeMemByte", pid..','..process..','..address + (i-1)..','..byte, DLL_RETURN_TYPE_INTEGER, DLL_CALL_CDECL)
            i = i + 1
        end
        DLL.CallFunction("hook.dll", "writeMemByte", pid..','..process..','..address + (i-1)..',0', DLL_RETURN_TYPE_INTEGER, DLL_CALL_CDECL)
    end
```

I basically need to adapt this to write a double value byte by byte.
I just can't think how to make the memory.writeDouble function.

EDIT: this is my readString function:

```
readString = function(pid, process, address)
        local i, str = 0, "" 
        repeat
            local curByte = DLL.CallFunction("hook.dll", "readMemByte", pid..','..process..','..(address + i), DLL_RETURN_TYPE_INTEGER, DLL_CALL_CDECL)
            if curByte == "" then curByte = 0 end
            curByte = tonumber(curByte)
            str = str .. string.char(curByte)
            i = i + 1
        until (curByte == 0)
        return str
    end,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first recommendation would be: try to find a function that accepts strings representing doubles instead of doubles. Implementing the lua side of that would be incredibly easy, since you already have a `writeString` - it could be something very similar to this:

```
writeDouble = function(pid, process, address, value)
  writeString(pid, process, address, tostring(value))
end
```

If you don't have that function, but you have access to the dll source, you can try to add that function yourself; it shouldn't be much more complicated than getting the string and then calling [atof](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atof) on it.

If you really can't modify the dll, then you need to figure out the exact double format that the lib is expecting - there are lots of factors that can change that format. The language and compiler used, the operative systems, and the compiler flags, to cite some.

If the dll uses a standard format, like [IEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008), the format will usually have well documented "translations" from/two bites. Otherwise, it's possible that you'll have to develop them yourself.

Regards and good luck!

Comment: Thanks, that was a good answer, I'll look into those options.

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries available for Lua that do just this.
If you need the resulting byte array (string), [string.pack](http://www.luteus.biz/Download/LoriotPro_Doc/LUA/LUA_For_Windows/lpack/index.html) should do it; you can find precompiled binaries for Windows included with [Lua for Windows](http://code.google.com/p/luaforwindows/).

If you are more interested in using the double to interface with foreign code, I would recommend taking a different approach using [alien](http://alien.luaforge.net/), a Foreign Function Interface library that lets you directly call C functions.

If you able to, I even more highly recommend switching to [LuaJIT](http://luajit.org/luajit.html), a Just-In-Time compiler for Lua that provides the power, speed and reach of C and assembly, but with the comfort an flexibility of Lua.

If none of these solutions are viable, I can supply some code to serialise doubles (not accessible at the moment).

Comment: If you could find the code to serialize doubles I'd greatly appreciate it, I'll look into the libraries but it's a small part of the program and I'd rather not add an entire library for what it's worth.